# Authorization in WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-authorization

I am building an admin page (MVC 5) using an AdminColntroller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class AdminController : ApplicationBaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I want to implement it as a single page application so I will be making client-side ajax calls to an admin web api which I also want to secure access to:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/admin")]
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class AdminApiController : ApiController
{
    [Route("echo")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetEcho()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {Result = "Hello World"});
    }
}
```

This is the ajax call I'm making form the admin view:

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajax("https://example.com/api/admin/echo").done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function(a,b,c) {
        console.log(a);
    });
</script>
```

This throws an error (fail() method): "Authorization has been denied for this request." I don't understand why - my user has a role Admin (that's why I am able to even get to the admin page), and if I remove `[Authorize]` from `GetEcho()` method and then set a breakpoint inside it, I see the correct User object. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: show us your jquery-ajax call

Comment: @CodeNotFound - updated with the ajax call

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using ? Windows, Active directory, External providers?

Comment: Built in ASP.NET Identity auth mechanism, with login and password. The one that a new MVC project comes with (used to be called forms auth - what's the new name?)

Comment: That'd be using cookies rather than tokens.  As a work around, you can set `withCredentials` to true when sending the ajax request, but it's not the best solution.

Comment: @BrendanGreen - What's interesting, teh webapi endpoint knows who the caller is - if I debug the web api endpoint (GetEcho method) I can see the correct User object. So I don't understand why it fails to recognize the role of the caller if it knows its identity

Comment: When you say debug, I presume you mean hitting the endpoint via the browser?  If so, the browser takes care of sending the cookies with the request, whilst the `ajax` call does not.

Comment: @BrendanGreen - by debug I mean debugging the WebApi backend code. I am removing [Authorize] attribute from AdminApiController method and setting a breakpoint inside GetEcho() method. When the breakpoint is hit, I check User object and it's a valid caller user.

Comment: Do you add the user roles to the claim when the user signs in (or can you verify that the claims identity of the user post login does have those claims regarding their roles)?

Comment: I am not setting the claim manually, it's being done by role management I assume. It works well for the actual page controller - if you look at the first code snippet for AdminController which is for the admin page, it's also secured fro Admin role only, and I get access to the page as an Admin.

Comment: Last comment before moving into chat.  "**admin**" does not equal "**Admin**" - is this just a cut and paste error?  It may have an impact.

Comment: Damn! @BrendanGreen - make it into a separate answer and I will mark it as one :) It was this typo indeed. Changed to Admin and it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you are having is that against the MVC controller, you have this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

Whilst against the API controller, you have this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
```

The role check is case sensitive.  If you change the API controller to use `Admin` instead of `admin`, it should solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You always have to carry by your authentication data or the user token (based on the authentication way you use) with your API request.

In plain jQuery it could look like

`$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function (xhr) {
     xhr.setRequestHeader("ownToken", authToken);`